# What am I supposed to do in Riddler's "Drain Pain" challenge?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

I see the *Batman Reserved* spot, but nothing happens when I land on it. I've landed on the wall inside the green neon circle with no results.

It looks like I'm supposed to turn the hole so it's over the room at each level, but I can't figure out how to rotate the circle.

**What am I supposed to do in the *Drain Pain* challenge?**

Comment: Ah, this is the area that I confused my other answer with the fans on.  You basically have to lower the Batmobile down to the ledge on the same level as the spikes and move left and right.  The wheels of the Batmobile will cause the ring of spikes to rotate.  Keep rotating to clear paths to go down as far as you can go.

Comment: @JeffMercado So obvious it just might work. :-) If you add that as  an answer, I'll accept it. This game sometimes makes me feel dumb. At least I figured out the spoiler ending: Bruce Wayne *is* Batman.

Comment: Was working on getting a video up for another question. Was thinking about doing a video for this but I've already cleared that area, it wouldn't be the same.

Comment: @JeffMercado I've got a video I'll add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have to lower the Batmobile down to the ledge on the same level as the spikes and move left and right. The wheels of the Batmobile will cause the ring of spikes to rotate. Keep rotating to clear paths to go down as far as you can go.

The different slopes you can go down are numbered one to three.  Just follow the order of the slopes to get down to the next level.  For the first and second slopes, you'll want to turn it until you are over the spray painted bat logo for each level.  The third level, you'll have to backtrack and go to the first and second slopes to open up the path.